# Making specific Text Boldefaced in a TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, bold

Hi I currently have a texbox that prints out info to the user when they press diffrent buttons. I was wondering if there was a way to make only some of my text bolded while the rest isnt.

Ive tried the following:

```
textBox1.FontWeight = FontWeights.UltraBold;
textBox1.Text. = ("Your Name: " );
TextBox1.FontWeight = FontWeights.Regular;
textBox1.Text += (nameVar);
```

Only problem is that using this way will either make everything bold or nothing.
Is there a way to do this? Im using WPF project in C#

Any Comments or suggestions are appreciated.
Thanks!

EDIT: So now im trying to do the RichText box that you all suggested but I cant seem to get anything to appear in it:

```
// Create a simple FlowDocument to serve as the content input for the construtor.
FlowDocument flowDoc = new FlowDocument(new Paragraph(new Run("Simple FlowDocument")));
// After this constructor is called, the new RichTextBox rtb will contain flowDoc.
RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox(flowDoc);
```

rtb is the name of my richtextbox i created in my wpf

Thanks

Comment: Hmmm,I don't know if this will help you but in S.W.F(System.Windows.Forms) namespace threre is the RichTextBox class that has the SelectionFont propeerty.I don't know if it will work with WPF though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use a RichTextBox, below a method that i have wrote for this problem - hope it helps ;-)

```
/// <summary>
/// This method highlights the assigned text with the specified color.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="textToMark">The text to be marked.</param>
/// <param name="color">The new Backgroundcolor.</param>
/// <param name="richTextBox">The RichTextBox.</param>
/// <param name="startIndex">The zero-based starting caracter position.</param>
public static void ChangeTextcolor(string textToMark, Color color, RichTextBox richTextBox, int startIndex)
{
    if (startIndex < 0 || startIndex > textToMark.Length-1) startIndex = 0;

    System.Drawing.Font newFont = new Font("Verdana", 10f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, 178, false);
    try
    {               
        foreach (string line in richTextBox.Lines)
        { 
            if (line.Contains(textToMark))
            {
                richTextBox.Select(startIndex, line.Length);
                richTextBox.SelectionBackColor = color;
            }
            startIndex += line.Length +1;
        }
    }
    catch
    { }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use `TextBlock` with other `TextBlock`s or `Run`s inside:

```
<TextBlock>
    normal text
    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold">bold text</TextBlock>
    more normal text
    <Run FontWeight="Bold">more bold text</Run>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: How to programmatically do this?

Comment: @digz6666 By adding them to the `Inlines` collection.

Answer (score 11):

You will need to use a [`RichTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx) to achieve this:

```
<RichTextBox Name="richTB">
  <FlowDocument>
    <Paragraph>
      <Run FontWeight="Bold">Your Name:</Run>
      <Run Text="{Binding NameProperty}"/>
    </Paragraph>
  </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

But why would you want "Your Name" to be editable? Surely you would want it as a separate, readonly, label?

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label FontWeight="Bold">Your Name:</Label>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding NameProperty}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 4):

A regular `TextBox` only supports the *all or nothing* setting of such stylistic properties. You might want to look into [`RichTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx), though, you can't just specify a set of values for a `Text` property in the way you have tried - you will need to work with a [`FlowDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument.aspx) to construct your text body through the [`Document`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.document.aspx) property.

For an overview of working with a `FlowDocument`, and some examples, [give this a read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909.aspx).

Comment: so im trying a basic flowDocument in a rich text box and it doesnt seem to do anything -- im using the example from msdna: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597536.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [RichTextBox Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) it basically works the same as the TextBox but allows for more customization and takes, of course, [Rich Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) which allows for partial formatting..

Answer (score 0):

Taking jwillmer's excellent example, I made some adjustments because it was coloring the entire error line for me:

```
    public static void ChangeTextcolor(string textToMark, Color color, RichTextBox richTextBox)
    {
        int startIndex = 0;

        string text = richTextBox.Text;
        startIndex = text.IndexOf(textToMark);

        System.Drawing.Font newFont = new Font("Verdana", 10f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, 178, false);

        try
        {
            foreach (string line in richTextBox.Lines)
            {
                if (line.Contains(textToMark))
                {
                    richTextBox.Select(startIndex, textToMark.Length);
                    richTextBox.SelectionColor = color;
                    richTextBox.SelectionFont = newFont;
                }
            }
        }
        catch{ }
    }
```

Also, I added unique tags before and after the text to color to get the text, then removed them.

Answer (score 0):

jwillmer's answer had a few errors for me. These were solved by adding:

```
using System.Drawing;
```

and then changing the inputs to:

```
public static void ChangeTextcolor(string textToMark, System.Drawing.Color color, System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox richTextBox, int startIndex)
```

This was because my code was looking for `System.Windows.Controls.RichTextbox` not `Windows.Forums.RichTextBox`. And `System.Windows.Media.Color` not `System.Drawing.Color`