# How can I bold text in ASP .NET

Tags: asp.net

How can I bold my output like this

Student "**John**" assigned to Officer "**Mick**".

i want **John** and **Mick** bold in web

This is my code aspx :

> this.lblAssignee.Text = " Student \"" +
>   StudentAssign + "\" assigned to Officer \"" + objAssign.FullName +
>   "\".";

Comment: Possable duplicate post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403902/making-specific-text-bolded-in-a-textbox)

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
this.lblAssignee.Text = " Student \"<b>" + StudentAssign + "</b>\" assigned to Officer \"<b>" + objAssign.FullName + "</b>\".";
```

or this (better maintainability)

```
this.lblAssignee.Text = " Student \"<span class='highlight'>" + StudentAssign + "</span>\" assigned to Officer \"<span class='highlight'>" + objAssign.FullName + "</span>\".";
```

and in your stylesheet

```
.highlight { font-weight: bold; }
```

Comment: +1 for *not* using bold tags although strong/em may be better than a span and a class

Comment: Isn't strong preferred to b ?

Comment: strong/em probably would be preferable to b but they are not strictly the same (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243074/is-it-ok-to-use-strong-in-place-of-b-blindly) so will leave that up to the OP to decide.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be setting the Font.Bold property of the label to True.

Something like:

```
myLabel.Font.Bold = True
```

Assuming you can use several labels of course.