# highlight a word in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a standard input field:

`<input type='text' id='txt'>`

And let's say the contents are `foo bar`.

Now, I want to be able to dynamically, with javascript/jQuery highlight the word 'bar' in that input field.  I've tried using things such as `$('#txt').setSelectionStart(5);` or `$('#txt').selectionStart(5);`, but nothing seems to work.  How can I do this?  All the examples point to code within the `$('#txt').select()` scope, but I need to be able to change it from other places.

**Edit** By *highlight* I mean *select* or *highlight* a word in the same way you would select a word with your mouse to edit it or copy.  **I do not mean** to simply color the word differently.

**Second Edit** After an entire morning, I finally managed it.  My big hangup was not preventing default when pressing an arrow key.  here is the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/31mts93v/3/

Comment: what do you mean by *highlight the word*

Comment: Try using Rich Text box:
This link might help you "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403902/making-specific-text-bolded-in-a-textbox" .

Comment: setSelectionRange has 2 or 3 arguments. (selectionStart, selectionEnd, [optional] selectionDirection);

ex: an input with an id='a' has the value 'foo bar' 

if you run the code document.getElementById("a")setSelectionRange(0, 3) then 'foo' will be selected

Answer (score 6):

html is not allowed in input type text or textarea.

One way to do this would be to have a content editable div and then search for the text and add a highlight class to the matched text.

For ex.

```js
$('#keyWord').on('input', function (e) {
    var text = $(this).val();
    // escaping string for use in regex
    text = text.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
    var re = new RegExp(text, 'gi');
 
    $('#test').children().each(function () {
        // if no text input clear out previous .highlight spans
        if(!text){
            $(this).html($(this).text());
            return;
        }
        // if match for regex insert .highlight class
        $(this).html($(this).text().replace(re, function(match){
            return '<span class="highlight">'+ match   +'</span>';
        })); 
    });
});
```

```css
   .highlight{
  background: red;
}
#test{
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
<div contenteditable="true" id="test">
<p>This is bar</p>
</div>
</div>
Search text: <input type="text" id="keyWord" />
```

Comment: Hmm! I suppose I could use a content editable DIV.  I shall give that a go.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry It appears I was not clear enough in my question.  Please see again - I meant highlight as you would with a mouse to edit or copy text.

Comment: Oh. In that case please refer to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646611/programmatically-selecting-partial-text-in-an-input-field)

Answer (score 4):

Check this [Link](http://mistic100.github.io/jquery-highlighttextarea/)

This is a jquery plugin and this might help you in achieving your result.

I have used some string functions and setSelectionRange in order to select the text inside a text box.

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="Select" onmousedown="selectCup(); return false">
 <input type="text" id="select_text">
```

Js

```
function selectCup() {

    var search_text = document.getElementById("select_text").value;
    var n = search_text.length;
    var input = document.getElementById("test");
    var input_text = input.value;
    var x = input_text.indexOf(search_text);
    var y = x+n;
    input.focus();
    input.setSelectionRange(x, y); // Highlights "Cup"
};
```

I have udated in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avnaveen91/YNr7K/144/)

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to highlight, I want to select the word.  As in the same way you would 'select' or 'highlight' a word with your mouse.

Comment: I have created a fiddle and updated the above post. Please check it.

Note: this will select only the first occurrence of the text. and it is case sensitive.