# VB.NET Find Dialog for RichTextBox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, richtextbox

I am having some problems with creating a "Find" dialog for my text editor in Visual Studio 2017. I want this dialog to take input from the user, then scan a RichTextBox control, and highlight matches. The user might press "Find Next" if there are more than one match. Basically what I am looking for is a Notepad "Find" function. I did a lot of research but none fixed my problem. Thanks! 
P.S.I would like some basic code to accomplish this function.

Comment: What is your specific question? What do you expect as a result to this question?  Currently, this is too broad and will most likely be closed as such.

Comment: P.S. I would like some basic code for a "Find" function in VB.NET

Comment: This looks like partially what you want to do. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29162767/highlight-a-word-in-input-field