# How can i make a button for Bold a selected text in Textbox/Richtextbox in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to make a `Button` for bolding selected text of a `string` in `TextBox`/`RichTextBox`, but I don't know how to do it with code behind.

```
TextBox1.SelectedText = new FontStyle("Bold")
```

It is not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set specific text to bold in WPF RichTextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33559679/set-specific-text-to-bold-in-wpf-richtextbox)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code for a rich TextBox:

```
RichTextBox1.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold);
```